# Calling SignalR SendAsync after db.SaveChangesAsync in controller

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to call SignalR SendAsync-method that will push the booking to all admins after pushing booking to database. What happens is that the admin gets disconnected. 
When i try to call the method before _context.SaveChangesAsync(), it all works fine. But then i won't get the id created by database, so i need to be able to call the SignalR SendAsync-method after _context.SaveChangesAsync().

Someone got a clue of what i am doing wrong here?

```
    [Route("book")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BookingUser(BookingViewModel model)
    {
         Booking booking = new Booking();

         _context.Booking.Add(booking);
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

         var userids = await _context.UserInfo.Where(a => a.BoardingHouseId == model.BoardingHouseId).Select(a => a.AspNetUsersId).ToListAsync();
         await _hub.Clients.Groups(userids).SendAsync("newbooking", booking);

         return Ok();
    }
```

My client code looks like this:

```
let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                 .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
                 .withUrl(url, {
                      skipNegotiation: true,
                      transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
                  })
                  .build();

connection.start()
          .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection'));

connection.on("newbooking", data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: You need await this _hub.Clients.Groups(userids).SendAsync("newbooking", booking);

Comment: @itikhomi sorry i forgot that in my example. I do use await, and still keeps disconnecting when calling after SaveChangesAsync();

Comment: I try to achieve same functionality within my SignalR application, but can not reproduce same issue. And the code snippet `await _hub.Clients.Groups(userids).SendAsync("newbooking", booking);` just help push data to specific clients who are in specific group(s), normally which would not cause clients disconnected. Please clarify when and how you call action `BookingUser` and please show the code of client method `newbooking`, so that we can troublesshot the issue better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @FeiHan. I have now added the client code in my post. The issue seems to be with the booking-object after i have run the await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); I tried to run await _hub.Clients.Groups(userids).SendAsync("newbooking", "Hello world"); just for fun, and that worked. I also manage to return the booking-object if i run the method before SaveChangesAsync(), but as i said i need to have the id with me.

Comment: To troubleshoot the issue, you can try to enable DetailedErrors by setting `hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true` and [enable client logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=dotnet#configure-client-options). Besides, if possible, you can share example data of Booking object that you pushed to client(s).

Comment: @FeiHan didn't solve the original issue, but i solved it using JsonConvert.SerializeObject on my object. Seems like the issue was passing the object with at least 3 nested levels of data.

Comment: `admin gets disconnected` → how do you know that the admin gets disconnected?